# Copy and Paste Data from A & B cell To C by giving preference to A

Tags: excel, vba

Need a macro
I want to copy two columns A & B to a new cell C. All the data in A should be copied as it is in C and after that the data from B Should be copied to the blank cells of C

This is the way i want the column C as in the table

eg:

```
A       B       C
Live    Life    Live
Love    Gain    Love
        Picture Picture
        Perfect Perfect
Throw   Use Throw
```

Please help!

Comment: please refer to help-center how to ask and what is on topic on this site. This is not a place where you request macros to be written. its a specific site for programming related problems. I find nothing programming related in your question therefore its off topic for here.

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1,B1)
```

and copy down